# NSURLCache caches "null" responses

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

I've been really struggling to implement this "automatic" and "transparent" NSURLCache.  One of my problems is that it caches null responses, which is rather annoying.  You would tell me to implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate method "willCacheResponse", however these are synchronous requests issued with NSURLConnection's class method "sendSynchronousRequest", so I have no instance to set a delegate on.

How can I prevent NSURLCache from caching null responses while using the class method ("sendSynchronousRequest") on NSURLConnection for synchronous requests???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you could prevent the cache of a specific request but you can remove it from the cache if the response data is nil/null using:

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];